# Broken link/launch behaviour on Kubuntu 11.10 desktop after rekonq uninstalled

Tags: desktop-environment

Since I removed rekonq from my system, numerous apps which launch links, e.g. Stackapplet and Thunderbird are not correctly launching links with Firefox, which I am using now as my primary browser.

I need a global way of telling Kubuntu to automatically launch links inside apps with Firefox,   I have tried changing file associations but that appears to be irrelevant. 
[image]

System Kubuntu 11.10 64-bit

@rozcietrzewiacz - your suggested solution can be found here:
[image]

Comment: There is a separate system setting called something like "default browser program" - look for it. (Sorry, I don't know where it can be found on KDE).

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Thanks!  That did it!  In `Applications > Settings> System Settings > Default Applications`.  See screenshot in OP, and if you repost your comment as the solution, I will accept it.